# Не работает Chrome Canary

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

```
from selenium import webdriver
c = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
c.binary_location('C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe')
c.add_argument('headless')
c.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=c)
d.get('au.ru')
```

Ошибка:

> c.binary_location('C:/Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
> SxS\Application\chrome.exe') TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: c.binary_location = 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binary_location` - это строка, а не функция.

как и написал [@strawdog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/311069/strawdog) в комментарии:
`chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe'` должно работать